# select the 3 highest values using php mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this:

`id|value

1|2

2|8

3|5

4|6

5|10

6|7`

I need a query to pull AND sum the 3 highest values.  So the correct query would pull the following:

3 highest:

5|10
2|8
6|7

Sum of 3 highest values = 25

I feel like this should be pretty simple but i'm having a tough time!  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(Value) AS SumOfTop3Values
FROM (
    SELECT Value
    FROM Table
    ORDER BY Value DESC
    LIMIT 3
) AS sub
```

Comment: i'm not able to echo out the sum?  I have:   $query = 
    "SELECT SUM(value) AS SumOfTop3Values
 FROM (
    SELECT price
    FROM table
    ORDER BY value DESC
    LIMIT 3) AS sub";
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $numb_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $total = $row['SUM(value)'];  echo $total;
    }

Comment: @robmelino You need to refer to the sum using the alias in the query (the `AS` clause) -- in this case, you would use `$row['SumOfTop3Values']`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to wrap this in a subquery:

```
SELECT SUM(value) AS total FROM (
    SELECT value FROM table
    ORDER BY value DESC
    LIMIT 3
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To have MySQL return highest 3 values and their Sum in a 4th row, you can use (aasuming that `id` is the Primary Key of the table):

```
SELECT id, SUM(value)
FROM
  ( SELECT id, value
    FROM TableX
    ORDER BY value DESC
    LIMIT 3
  ) AS tmp
GROUP BY id 
WITH ROLLUP ;
```